Implementing market sell/buy order with python-binance API: Overcoming constraints
I've been struggling to implement a market sell/buy order using the python-binance library through API, despite attempting alternatives like ccxt. My progress has hit a snag.
I retrieve Binance's order specifications data for a symbol using:
symbol_info = client.get_symbol_info(trading_pair)

which is described in
https://python-binance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/binance.html#binance.client.Client.get_symbol_info
So far, I've identified the following constraints for executing a market buy/sell order for a given trading pair:

The quantity must fall within the specified min-max range.
The quantity must be a multiple of the specified step size.
The decimal precision of the quantity must not exceed the default precision.

Below is the code I've been working on. The objective of this question is to create a functional buy or sell order that sells, say, 95% of the currency.
from binance.client import Client
from decimal import Decimal, ROUND_DOWN

# Load API keys
api_key = <Tha_key>
api_secret = <Tha_other_key>

# Initialize client
client = Client(api_key, api_secret)

# Get trading pair
trading_pair = 'BTCUSDT'

# Get available asset balance
asset = 'USDT'
info = client.get_account()
asset_balance = None
for balance in info['balances']:
    if balance['asset'] == asset:
        asset_balance = float(balance['free'])
        break

if asset_balance is None:
    print(f"No balance available for asset: {asset}")
else:
    # Calculate order quantity (95% of available balance)
    order_quantity = 0.95 * asset_balance

    # Get symbol info
    symbol_info = client.get_symbol_info(trading_pair)
    lot_size_filter = next(filter for filter in symbol_info['filters'] if filter['filterType'] == 'LOT_SIZE')

    # Extract the step size, minQty and maxQty from the LOT_SIZE filter
    step_size = Decimal(lot_size_filter['stepSize'])
    min_qty = Decimal(lot_size_filter['minQty'])
    max_qty = Decimal(lot_size_filter['maxQty'])

    # Adjust quantity to match Binance standards
    order_quantity = Decimal(order_quantity)
    if step_size != 0.0:
        order_quantity = step_size * round(order_quantity / step_size)

    # Check if order quantity is within the minQty and maxQty limits
    if order_quantity < min_qty or order_quantity > max_qty:
        print(f"Order quantity {order_quantity} is outside the allowed range ({min_qty}, {max_qty})")
    else:
        # Adjust order quantity to the digit precision given by symbol info
        base_asset_precision = int(symbol_info['baseAssetPrecision'])
        order_quantity = order_quantity.quantize(Decimal(f'0.{"0" * base_asset_precision}'), rounding=ROUND_DOWN)

        # Place market order
        order = client.order_market_buy(
            symbol=trading_pair,
            quantity=float(order_quantity)
        )

        print(f"Market order placed: {order}")


The error (this time) is:
~/.venv/bin/python ~/myfile.py.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/myfile.py", line 54, in <module>
    order = client.order_market_buy(
  File "~/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/binance/client.py", line 1614, in order_market_buy
    return self.order_market(**params)
  File "~/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/binance/client.py", line 1586, in order_market
    return self.create_order(**params)
  File "~/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/binance/client.py", line 1448, in create_order
    return self._post('order', True, data=params)
  File "~/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/binance/client.py", line 418, in _post
    return self._request_api('post', path, signed, version, **kwargs)
  File "~/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/binance/client.py", line 378, in _request_api
    return self._request(method, uri, signed, **kwargs)
  File "~/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/binance/client.py", line 359, in _request
    return self._handle_response(self.response)
  File "~/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/binance/client.py", line 368, in _handle_response
    raise BinanceAPIException(response, response.status_code, response.text)
binance.exceptions.BinanceAPIException: APIError(code=-1013): Filter failure: MARKET_LOT_SIZE

Process finished with exit code 1

I'd greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to troubleshoot this issue. Thanks in advance!
`
I am trying to place a real market buy/sell order in Binance and is so impossible!
